# LinkedIn HTML audio autoplay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I have simple audio in my app I want to add audio to play automatically when the user open in my site via LinkedIn browser

Here  is my html

```
 <audio  onloadeddata="this.play()"  id="audioplayer" playsinline="true" webkit-playsinline controls loop autoplay muted>
        <source src="audio/muzyka_meed_loop.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"> Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
```

Unfortunately, this is not working

What do I need to change to get this working?

Comment: Most browsers prevent any audio being played on page load without user interaction, as it's incredibly annoying. I doubt you'll be able to make this work without the user doing something to start the audio, such as click an 'unmute' or 'play' button.

Comment: Some client doesn't understand this :( when u say most browsers prevent this behavior :(

Answer (score 0):

You have do it like below. Add "autoplay" to audio tag.

```
<audio autoplay id="audioplayer" controls>
    <source src="audio/muzyka_meed_loop.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Note: The audio tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.